# map only one column in a JoinTable relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have 3 tables:

**BusinessRole**

- identifier
- name

**BusinessRole_ActorType(link table)**

- role_identifier
- actorType_identifier

**ActorType**

- identifier
- name(varchar)

I need to create a JPA Entity, BusinessRole, that joins the tables and provides a list of actorTypes in the entity while using only the name from the ActorType table.

I know I can achieve similar result by creating a `ActorType` entity and adding a `@ManyToMany` with a `@JoinTable`, but this would add an extra object and I am only interested in the String value.

The code below shows what I want to achieve.

```
@Entity
public class BusinessRole {

    //TODO: Fill in with appropriate annotations :)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(....)
    private List<String> assignableActorTypes;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't create any entity for ActorType, hibernate would not be able to access that table, because there is no possible way for hibernate to know its existence.

If you really don't want to create the model for ActorType, then you can use native SQL queries. But be sure to check for SQL injections as native sql queries are more prone to such attacks.

But I don't think there is any possible way to have List, like you are looking for.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement. For example @CollectionTable(name = "table_name" ...) or @JoinTable(name="table_name" ..) both use tables that don't have an entity created. What I want to achieve might not be possible, but I don't think that is the reason. Frankly I don't understand why this is not possible, it is a normal scenario and from my pov should be resolved by @CollectionTable as this is a normalization of CollectionTable

Comment: @Alex Escu agreed, but you use '@CollectionTable' and '@joinTable' over field for related ENTITY, having a relationship. Also, when we use '@joinTable', the mapping table contains only 2 fields(primary identifier of both the tables). If we need to have anymore columns in that mapping table, I don't think we can without creating a new mapping Entity. And what you are looking for is map an entity to a column/field of a table/entity, rather than entity itself

Comment: @AlexEscu 'but I don't think that is the reason' - you're absolutely right. The reason why it's impossible is quite simple, really: anything that has its own identity is, by definition, an entity. Since `ActorType` has an `identifier`, it cannot be modelled as anything else but one

Comment: Think of it like this: one of your entities is associated to `(1, 'ActorOne'), (2, 'ActorOne')` through `assignableActorTypes`. You then remove one of the `"ActorOne"` strings from the collection, and update the entity. Should JPA delete the association to `(1, 'ActorOne')` or to `(2, 'ActorOne')`? How is it supposed to know?